# observable beforeShowDay jqui datepicker event

Tags: jquery, datepicker, knockout.js

I am using the datepicker binding made by rpn (http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html).
I'm struggling a little when integrating the beforeShowDay event.

I want to highlight days in the calendar, so i add the

```
beforeShowDay: function (currentDay) { //logic  if currentDay is within observableArray then highlight };
```

But that logic is depending on data (observableArray) from an ajax call.

How can i tell the datepicker to update its highlighted dates when the observableArray used in beforeShowDay-function updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe on your observableArray change and within event function refresh datepicker to re-render it's content.

```
self.YourArray.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    // re-init or re-render datepicker
});
```

Comment: But it's initialized by the knockout binding. And if i do $('#datepicker').datepicker(); i got an exception (datepicker cannot set property 'currentday' of undefined). Is it somehow possible to re-applybindings?

Comment: I think you can try reset value for date observable property that using with datepicker that should cause re-render and this will fire beforeShowDay function with you changed array like myDate(myDate()). It's a little bit tricky but it should work